# Exception in Application Start method caused by initialize method

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

This is one of my first projects using FXML and I'm having issues in my initialize method and loading my FXML file in general.

I'm not sure what I'm missing but any help with the program would be appreciated.

Exerpt from Controller Class:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML TextField input;
    @FXML TextArea output;
    @FXML RadioMenuItem chooseLonghand;
    @FXML RadioMenuItem chooseRoman;
    @FXML Button addInput;
    String number;
    Object conversion;
    Alert alert;
    BufferedNumberConverter converter;

    TextInputDialog retry = new TextInputDialog("Enter a valid integer");

    public Controller(){

    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        final ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
        chooseLonghand.setToggleGroup(group);
        chooseRoman.setToggleGroup(group);
    }
```

Launcher Class:

```
public class Launcher extends Application {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.setTitle("Number Converter");
        stage.show();

        // Close all windows when primaryStage closed
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(ev -> System.exit(0));

    }
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ragog.Controller">
   <children>
      <TextArea layoutY="200.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="600.0" />
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="91.0" text="Enter a number:" />
      <TextField layoutX="105.0" layoutY="10.0" />
      <Button layoutX="265.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addInput" text="Add Input" />
      <RadioButton layoutX="160.0" layoutY="56.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseLonghand" text="Rewrite in longhand" />
      <RadioButton layoutX="160.0" layoutY="85.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseRoman" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="177.0" text="Rewrite in roman numerals" />
      <Button layoutX="355.0" layoutY="81.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#rewrite" text="Rewrite!" />
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="158.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#output" text="Output:" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither `chooseLonghand` nor `chooseRoman` has a corresponding element in the fxml file. You only use `onAction` event handlers with the same name for the `<RadioButton>` elements. (I'm not sure why this does not result in an exception before `FXMLLoader` even gets to the point where `initialize` is invoked.)

For this reason both fields are `null` when the `initialize` method is invoked.

You need to add `fx:id`s to the elements that should be injected to the controller:

```xml
<RadioButton fx:id="chooseLonghand" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="56.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseLonghand" text="Rewrite in longhand" />
<RadioButton fx:id="chooseRoman" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="85.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseRoman" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="177.0" text="Rewrite in roman numerals" />
```